# Regex replace linebreak and comma

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

i've a question about regex, i've a text and it looks like below :

```
car,model,serie
,Mercedes,324,1,
,BMW,23423,1,
,OPEL,54322,1,
```

it should look like:

```
car,model,serie
Mercedes,324,1,
BMW,23423,1,
OPEL,54322,1,
```

so without commas at the beginning of the text.

What i tried :

```
var str2 = str.replace(/\n|\r/g, "");
```

but somehow, i couldn't add comma in regex.

can anyone help me? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: From where do you get this formatted text? Cannot you simply change its source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been a lot of responses to this question and for a newbie to regex it is probably a bit overwelming,

## Overall the best response has been:

```
var str2 = str.replace(/^,/gm, '');
```

This works by using **^**, to check if the first character is a comma and if it is, remove it. It also uses the **g** and **m** flags to do this for the first character of every line.

#### If you are curious about the other versions then read on:

**1:**

```
var str2 = str.replace(/^,+/gm, '');
```

This is a slight variant in that it will remove multiple consecutive commas at the beginning of each line, but based off of your dataset this is not required.

**2:**

```
var str2 = str.replace(/\n,/g, '\n');
```

This version works exactly the same as the first, however it finds each newline follow by a comma with **\n**, and replaces it with another newline.

**3:**

```
var str2 = str.replace(/(\n|\r),/g, '$1')
```

This version is the same as the previous however it doesn't make the assumption that the newline is a **\n**, it instead captures any newlines or carriage returns, it works the same as the **m** flag and **^,**.

**4:**

```
var str2 = str.replace(/\n+|\r+|,+/g,"\n")
```

And finally there is this, this is a combination of all the previous regex's, it makes the assumption that you may have a lot mixed newlines and commas without any text, and that you would want to remove all of those characters, it is unnecessary for your examples.

Comment: No problem @aldimeola1122 Once you have found a suitable answer make sure to select it using the tick symbol under the down vote symbol :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var str2 = str.replace(/(\n|\r),/g, '$1')
```

Your comma was actually placed outside the regex pattern, so you weren't far off :)

Comment: That will not put the newline back, you would need to change it to: var str2 = str.replace(/(\n|\r),/g, '$1');

Comment: yep, sorry, missed the second parameter, editing now

Answer (score 1):

Use this syntax:

```
str.replace(/^,/gm, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `multiline` flag and replace leading commas:

```
str = str.replace(/^,+/gm);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jK2aL1/1)